# is there any way to attribute a number for set of pixels?

Tags: image-processing

is there a way to generate a number for set of pixels (for example generate a number for 16 x 16 grey pixels) ?
after applying some filters and IP algorithms in many steps i want to save the corresponding result of this set of pixels so i need to have a suitable memory address ( a number) for saving the result,

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you please explain it better. What should the number be? You want to generate a number for 16x16 grey pixels - ok, I am going to generate the number - it's 7. Is that good? Do you see?

Comment: It is impossible to take any arbitrary combination of pixels and convert it to a *unique* number - that would be one heck of a compression algorithm if you could pull it off! What you can do is use a *hash* of some kind on the pixel values, but there will always be the possibility that two different images will generate the same hash.

Comment: If you are looking for some way to address a submatrix within an image, you will have to tell us what language or library you are using. If I misunderstand your question, please clarify.

Comment: i am using Matlab software , about my question : some image processing algorithms are applied to an sub-images (small size of image) and then i have  unique scalar results , i want to save this results to memory and i need to generate address (scalar number)  for saving them, hash algorithm is a good idea but i don't know how can i generate hash when i have 16*16=256 pixels (256 bytes),

Comment: Your description is still very vague. Please edit your question to include a small code sample that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve. You should add the `Matlab` tag at the same time. Also, if you tag somebody in your comment like `@beaker`, they will be notified of your response.

Comment: If you have 16x16 array of 8 bit values then that *is* a unique number, it's a 256 byte number but I suspect that's not what you want. When you say you want to save the result to memory, what exactly do you mean ? Do you want to use it as a lookup value or key for accessing the output scalar value from your image processing at a later date ? If you are trying to store all of the possible outcomes from every possible 16x16 greyscale input then hashing isn't going to help you as you'll need to store every conceivable value. It would help to understand *why* you need this number.

Comment: @DaveDurbin I want to use it as a lookup value and save the results in this look up table , i want to generate a suitable keys for saving/accessing the result value in this look up table,

Comment: @Sorena Will you be processing every possible 16x16 matrix? If so, you will have 256^256 possible values to store. This is A Very Big Number and you should probably think very hard about whether you really want to do this. You certainly won't be able to store it in memory.  If you want to only have a smaller subset of these possible values then using some sort of HashTable would probably be the best way to manage it. You don't mention what language/tool set you are using so I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question, and intentions, are really unclear, but the following may help you generate a useable hash... or it may be no use at all, so I won't make it very long or detailed.

- Take your 16x16 array, i.e. 256 values.
- Calculate their average.
- For each of the 256 values, generate a `1` if the pixel is brighter
  (greater) than the average, else generate a `0`.
- You will now have 256 zeroes and ones which you can represent as a 64 hex character string to use for whatever you are up to.

It's based on some work by Dr Neal Krawetz for *Perceptual Hashing*.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i am trying to find the accuracy of this hash method for all of possible input and find how many different input generate the same result, is there another hash method  for this type of implementation ? ,

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. It can generate 2^256 different values. It will obviously fail if your images are all entirely uniform/constant... but if your images are half-way normal, it should work pretty well. You will have to experiment really - I can't say better than that.